# Implementing component based design with DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, components, software-design

I'm new to DDD but have some idea about it. I have plan to develop component base application with C#. First I have created ER diagram and with that I have created db schema.

I chose component like EmployeeManagement, ProjectManagement and ResourceAllocation. But both EmployeeManagement and ResourceAllocation components use Employees table and also ProjectManagement and ResourceAllocation components use Projects table.

I have separated DataAccessLayer files for each components to access dbContext. Is this a quality wise acceptable solution or is there any other ways to improve current design?

Comment: The essence of DDD is not much related to technical patterns. Read about strategic DDD patterns and you will notice that your question doesn't really relate to DDD.

Answer (score 1):

First, your database design has nothing to do with DDD or how your domain model looks like.

If your question is about design patterns, probably the [repository pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-cplusdoneplusright) is what you are looking for.

If you want to use [DDD principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), start by designing a domain model (defining aggregates, entities, value objects etc) and don't think of databases or technical details.